# Selenium Chrome Webdriver - Obtaining Youtube Hover Text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to scrape some data from Youtube to use in order to train a model (I just started learning AI, so I'm just doing a test project).  I am having an issue where in order to get the exact view count and date a video was published, given its watch URL, the webdriver must obtain the hover text of the info container. I have looked online for other solutions but using tooltips has not worked for me (I may have implemented it wrong). Here is a sample image of the data I am attempting to obtain.
[image]

Comment: [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part)`=`[`snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet)`,`[`statistics`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics) solves your issue by retrieving [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) and [`viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount).

Comment: Hello, I am aware of this, I am looking however to solve my issue through scraping alone to improve my skills. How would I do this?